# nice permalink for frontend edit page

Tags: permalinks, front-end

I would like to know if anyone has ever tried to create a permalink like this for editing a post in the frontend:

http://example.com/books/750/edit

Where *books* is my **custom post type**, *750* the **custom post type id** and *edit* the **edit page slug**.
I know I could do something like http://example.com/books/edit/?id=750 but's that not very friendly.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure you could use the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to pull this off in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Please do not just dump links here. Add an explanation and an example how to use it.